# Unclear scala compiler behaviour when using shapeless to map over tuples

Tags: scala, shapeless

Assume the following setup:

```
val f = new (Int -> Int)(_ + 1)
object g extends (Int -> Int)(_ + 1)
```

Then we have

```
(1,2) map g 
(2,3)
```

But

```
(1,2) map f
```

fails to compile with error

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.tuple.Mapper[(Int, Int),f.type]
          (1,2) map f
```

but (f == g) in terms of ->[A,B], so what am I missing?